# Include HTML/PHP in AngularJS variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I have the following JS code:

```
{var c;a.stores=[{name:"Nijiya Market",price:"$$",sales:292,rating:4},{name:"Eat On Monday Truck",price:"$",sales:119,rating:4.3}]
```

I call on these variables to produce an html table. What I want to do is use html within the JS variable to produce an image instead of text. So for example:

```
{var c;a.stores=[{name:"<img src='url'>",price:"$$",sales:292,rating:4},{name:"<img src='url'>",price:"$",sales:119,rating:4.3}]
```

Can anyone suggest how I do this and if the same method would work with php.

Don't know if it matters, but I am using AngularJS.

Thanks.

Comment: That should work fine if you're just gonna display it on a html page, have you tried it?

Comment: @ChrisEvans yes. It just appears as <img src='url'> see image: http://s24.postimg.org/85vg1sx3p/Screen_Shot_2015_05_06_at_04_03_26.png

Comment: you should have name: "<img src='" + url + "'>"

Comment: @ChrisEvans that just causes it to error and the page to not load.

Comment: need to use `ng-bind-html` to pass `<img>` to template because it isn't text. Angular expressions only take text. But would make more sense to just send the url and use `ng-src` in an image tag within the template. Suppose you wanted a css class later on the images...would only need to add it once in template and not have to update your database or php or whatever is now creating that `<img>`